# On the matrix equation $(A-\det(A)I)^n=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> I noticed in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400662/find-eigenvalues-of-unspecified-matrix) question that for an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, the expression
>   $$(A-\det(A)I)^n=0$$
>   is a set of $n^2$ equations in $n^2$ unknowns. Hence, it might fully determine $A$. Is this the case? What can we say about $A$?

What I can say is that $A$ has only one eigenvalue equal to $\det(A)$ and hence
$$\det(A)=\det(A)^n$$
so either $\det(A)=0$ or $\det(A)$ is an $(n-1)$th root of unity.

Comment: If $A$ is a $1\times1$ matrix, this equation says nothing about $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is any matrix  with the single eigenvalue $\lambda$, where, as you said, $\lambda$ is either $0$ or an $n-1$'th root of unity. The Jordan canonical form of such a matrix has all diagonal entries $\lambda$ and all entries on the first super-diagonal in $\{0,1\}$.  So $A$ is anything of the form $S J S^{-1}$ where $S$ is an invertible matrix and $J$ is such a Jordan canonical form.

Comment: @sfd I don't think you can give any other characterization of such matrices other than $SJS^{-1}$ for any invertible $S$ and $J$ as described. What kind of characterization are you looking for?

Comment: Gotcha. It's hard sometimes with edits. =)

Answer (score 1):

Any matrix with $A^n=0$ will work, and there are infinitely many when $n\geq 2$. For example, the zero matrix with any nonzero number in the upper right has $A^2=0$. Note in your last equation $\mathrm{det}(A)=0$ is a possibility.

Comment: +1 because this is already a wide set of solutions. Nevertheless, it would be good to prove that these are the only solutions (if this is the case).

Comment: My question is actually to find *all* matrices $A$...

Comment: @sdf: as written it was a bit unclear. You asked whether $A$ was fully determined by that equation, and my answer shows that it isn't. Anyway, Robert Israel has given a complete answer in the mean time.